# How will be faster get the file extension C#

Tags: c#, .net

How will be faster get the file extension

```
string ext = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(FileName);
```

```
string ext=FileName.Substring(FileName.LastIndexOf('.'));
```

```
System.IO.FileInfo fi = new System.IO.FileInfo(FileName);
string ext = fi.Extension;
```

```
string[] temp= FileName.Split('.');
string ext =temp[temp.Length-1];
```

```
System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex extend = new 
                           System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(@"(?:.*\.)(.*)");
string ext = extend.Match(FileName).Groups[1].Value;
```

Comment: How about measuring it if you are interested how the different approaches perform?

Comment: Additionally, using `Split` is a waste. And if you perform LastIndexOf, notice that a file can have no extension at all and exception is ready throw itself all over you.

Comment: [Which is faster ?](http://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/)

Comment: see stopwatch class to measure the time -> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch(v=vs.100).ASPX

Comment: I can measure it. But i thought someone done it. And this is good way to collect all version.

Comment: My tests with Stopwatch:

System.IO.Path.GetExtension: ext=.txt milSec=00:00:00.0000016

Substring: ext=.txt milSec=00:00:00.0000019

System.IO.FileInfo: ext=.txt milSec=00:00:00.0000445

Split: ext=txt milSec=00:00:00.0000009

System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex: ext=txt milSec=00:00:00.0004294

I think it's important if you have very many files...

Comment: How many files do you think it will take before it becomes an issue? Looking at those number, you are talking tens of millions before the 'problem' becomes noticeable. At that point, I'm betting there's something else that is taking several orders of magnitude longer that makes this time saving irrelevant.

Comment: You're right!) This question just Friday joke... I just want known, what people use to.

Comment: When I break out my trusty copy of ILSpy I examine the code to find that IndexOf calls out to some unmanaged Windows call to determine position of the "." character, whereas GetExtension simply loops back from the last character looking for the "." character. Because the GetExtension is dealing with a Path explicitly it doesn't need to check any Ordinal or Culture settings (unlike string comparison carried out in IndexOf) it can be more efficient. I struggle to see how anything could be faster than GetExtension but also fail to see why you'd choose to use anything but that method.

Comment: I need check, parse and load about hundred thousand files. As well as friday, what else to do on a friday. And by the way, i always used GetExtension...

Comment: 100k files is nothing, we've already spent more time on this question than you could ever save using any other method.

Comment: Блин.... It question was for fun!!!

Answer (score 2):

In case of such operations your first concern should be which one is more idiomatic, maintainable and readable. The first and the third version are examples of these. In the second and the last one you're trying to reinvent the wheel, making the code less readable and more error prone.

In VM frameworks performance is achieved through higher-level optimisations, like controlling the number of allocated objects, references between them etc. Things you talk about here are minor and probably irrelevant in terms of performance.

Comment: I not asked what is version correct and good to use. I asked what is faster and why? Read question before answer pls.

Comment: @EvgeniyDovgal I did read the question, and it's ill-posed. Performance depends on particular use case, so deducing what *will* be faster from your question is impossible. On the other hand if you really want to know which of these single lines with no context runs faster, then you can just measure this yourself, no need to ask others to do it for you. And probably you won't notice the difference in your results, or they will be statistically negligible.